# VBA: interact with javascript popup window in IE

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation, popup

I started automating a report. it's interacting with a website on our intranet for reporting. Once I get the interaction with the dropdown to execute it bring up a popup where I need to enter pre-generated text data and have it click OK so it can continue onward.

This is the snippet from the intranet webpage:

```html
                            <pre>
                            <form action="/Report/MarkJob" method="post">
                                <select name="status">
                                    <option value="">--Select One--</option>
                                    <option value="Mark Completed">Mark Completed</option>
                                    <option value="Non Voting">Non Voting</option>
                                    <option value="Foreign Client">Foreign Client</option>
                                    <option value="Dump / Purge">Dump / Purge</option>
                                    <option value="Job Closed">Job Closed</option>
                                    <option value="Test Job">Test Job</option>
                                    <option value="Unflagged for N&amp;A">Unflagged for N&amp;A</option>
                                    <option value="Email Only">Email Only</option>
                                    <option value="Canada NTC">Canada NTC</option>
                                    <option value="Bulk Shipment">Bulk Shipment</option>
                                    <option value="Not Following Day 40">Not Following Day 40</option>
                                    <option value="No Options">No Positions</option>
                                </select>
                                <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field     is required." id="item_ID" name="item.ID" type="hidden" value="16973962"><input id="comments"   name="comments" type="hidden" value="">
                                <input type="submit"    value="Select" onclick="javascript:return ShowMessage();">
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script>
function submitdata(){
    var valtext = $("#PPNumber").val(); //you can do also by  getelementbyid
    window.location.href = '/Report/Search/' + valtext;
}
function ShowMessage() {
    var result = prompt("Please insert a comment if required.", "");
    if (result == null) {
        return false; //break out of the function early
    }
    document.getElementById('comments').value = result;
    return true;
}
</script>
```

And the webpage screenshot:

[image: webpage screenshot]

This is the code I tried:

```vb
Sub DropDayMacro()

    '
    ' DropDayMacro Macro
    '

    Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim A As String

    ActiveCell.Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        JobNumber = Mid(ActiveCell.Value, 1, 6)
        Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
        ie.Visible = True
        ie.Navigate "http://10.23.16.37/Report/Search"
        Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
        ie.document.getElementById("PPNumber").Value = JobNumber
        ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "submitdata();", "javascript"
        Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
        na = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Status = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        If Status = "CL" Then
            A = "Job Closed"
        ElseIf na = "N" Then
            A = "Unflagged for N&A"
        End If
        ie.document.getElementsByTagName("select").Item(0).Value = A
        ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "ShowMessage();", "javascript"
        ie.document.getElementById("item_ID").Value = "AS PER PROXY PLUS NOTES"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the thread, It looks like you want to assign the value to HTML prompt.

You can refer example below may help you to do that.

VBA Code:

```
Private Const msFILENAME As String = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\66.html"

Public Sub demo()

'* Tools->References
'SHDocVw    Microsoft Internet Controls C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ieframe.dll

    Dim oIE As InternetExplorerMedium
    Set oIE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    oIE.Visible = True
    oIE.navigate msFILENAME
    While oIE.Busy Or oIE.readyState < 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Stop
    Call oIE.document.parentWindow.execScript("function prompt(){return 'demo_value_from_VBA'}")
    Stop
   ' oIE.Quit
End Sub
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button id="btn1" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script> function myFunction() {   var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");   if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";   } } </script>

</body> </html>
```

Output:

[image]

Further, You can try to modify this code example as per your requirement.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be what i need, though i appreciate your time. Unless I'm not understanding.  I am able to have VBA select the correct exception for the job in the drop down and execute the select button, which the opens a comment prompt popup. for the report I'm doing the comment is always "As Per Proxy Plus".  Also I noticed that if I manually paste in the comment and click OK it doesn't appear to actually do anything, versus when I press "Select" so that another issue I'm noticing.

Comment: Do you mean, When you try to add comment to prompt than nothing happens? and it works only when you had made any selection in dropdown? Is there any way for you to confirm that your comments are getting inserted to your report or anywhere else? Please try to inform us if we are missing anything. From your question it only appears that you want to add value to prompt from VBA.

Comment: I'm sorry if i phrased the question improperly. I would like for vba to enter the comment for me. My 2nd issue now is that the command i used [ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "ShowMessage();", "javascript] brings up the comment box, but if a comment is entered it doesn't actually execute the selected drop down choice, the comment box just closes but the page does refresh to show that it took the exception and comment. but if i click [Select] and enter and comment it works.

Comment: For this issue, I suggest you to check whether any events or function get fired after you to insert the value to prompt. If you find any than try to call it from your VBA code may help you to move further.